# How can I make the form work when cookies are disabled?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, cookies

This is a java web app and in the .jsp file I have:

```
<form method="post" action="<% out.print(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath()+"/target.do")); %>"
      accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label for="name">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    </label>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And target.do is mapped to a servlet where doPost is:

```
HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
session.setAttribute("sessionName",httpServletRequest.getParameter("name"));
httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/target.jsp");
```

And in target.jsp I simply show the name:

```
Your Http Session name is:
<%
    String sessionName = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionName");
    out.print(sessionName);
%>
```

However, when cookies are disabled this will not work. I do not want to use .forward I need to use sendRedirect.

Application is deployed to Tomcat.

Putting the name in a request attribute is a possible solution but I am looking for URL encoding actually but I can not achieve it?

Edit: encodeURL instead of encodeRedirectURL does not work either.

Comment: Why do you want to urlencode the context path anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question:

```
This worked:         

httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(httpServletResponse.encodeRedirectURL(getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/target.jsp"));
```

and in the .jsp file encode... part is not required..